# What is the Const node in batch normalization in tensorflow.layers.batchnormalization

Tags: tensorflow, layer, tensor, batch-normalization, tensorrt

in tensorflow 1.14 
if use operation of tensorflow.layers.batch_normalization(fused=True) 
then generate batch_normalization/Const node,
i want to know that what is the const node and what is the role of that node,

also if training parameter in batch_normalization set True 
then const node become empty list but
if training parameter set False then that node has a value that is 0.99
i really really want to know what is this

Comment: In generally, in TensorFlow, each node represents the instantion of an operation. Each operation has some input, and can generate an output that is passed on to other nodes.